# How to designate a region for regional shipping charges by weight with drupal commerce?

Tags: location, commerce

My commerce shop needs ***different shipping charges by weight to different regions*** in the U.S.; the east coast, the mid-west, and the west-coast.

Such that *a 6oz package would have three different shipping charges depending on where it was going.*

I would imagine this need ***three different weight-based rules*** for shipping, I am specifically wondering about how to implements the conditional statements for these. I would imagine one way to implement this would be a series or AND/OR statements in the conditional, but for a case like the US, thus means sometimes 20+ AND-OR conditions on a state by state basis.

***Is there an easier way to designate a geographic region as a collection of states? Or is this the best and only way to implement this?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out [Commerce Shipping Postal Code Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_postal_code_weight), which sounds like it might solve your problem.